# No code coverage Sonar with powermock

Tags: unit-testing, sonarqube, powermock, sonarlint

I have written a test case using powermock and easymock. I have sonarlint plugin associated with local sonarqube server. When i run sonarlint analysis on my  test case no coverage is being shown. I know powermock disables eclemma coverage. Is this the same issue with sonarlint plugin too? Is there a way I can see unit test case coverage?

Comment: Probably. And in essence: the need to use PowerMock can very often be fixed by improving the quality of your code under test. When you follow the SOLID principles and guidance such as this https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79 ... you simply will not need PowerMock. It has its place testing legacy code you can't change - but when you test your own stuff: then, seriously: dont use PowerMock.

Comment: sonarlint plugin does not show code coverage.

Comment: @GhostCat its a legacy code only... still searching how to do it